# System.Speech.Recognition; background control or voice recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, system.speech.recognition

I'm not sure if it is possible but anyway,

I use `using System.Speech.Recognition;` in winform C# app.

I'm wondering if it is possible not only to recognize speech, but also recognize  voice,  somehow recognize difference between different voices

to get something near to reading of multiply content from each separate voice, for example from two simultaneously or separately speaking users as different two.

Or at least maybe some method to control background loudness, for example if `AudioLevelUpdated` event allows me to see input volume, but maybe also exist some specific way to separate loud voice from extra noise or voices in background

Comment: i'm afraid you are expecting too much from a free sdk...

Comment: @ Lei Yang  so it is impossible...

Comment: i'm not sure ^_^

Comment: @ Lei Yang I can't find any  information...

Answer (score 1):

`System.Speech.Recognition` will not help you in voice recognition.
`System.Speech.Recognition` is intended for speech to text. Adding grammar to it improves its efficiency. You can train the Windows desktop for better conversion. Refer Speech Recognition in Control Panel.

There are couple of 3rd party libraries available for voice recognition. 
For removal of noise, you can refer [Sound visualizer in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20025/Sound-visualizer-in-C).

You can find an interesting discussion at [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/121f3d98-df2c-4c3d-addf-d1fda4f71012/recognition-of-a-specific-persons-voice-with-sapi-based-on-trained-profiles-?forum=csharpgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [CRIS](https://www.cris.ai/) which is part of Microsoft Cognitive Services, at least for you question about noise.

CRIS is a Custom Speech Service and its basic use is to improve the quality of Speech-to-text using custom acoustics models (like background noise) and learning vocabulary using samples.

You can import :

- Acoustic Datasets
- Language Datasets
- Pronunciation Datasets

For example in acoustic models you have:

- Microsoft Conversational Model for recognizing speech spoken in a conversational style (i.e. speech directed at another person).
- Microsoft Search and Dictation Model for speech directed to an application, such as commands, search queries or dictation.

There is also a [Speaker Recognition API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/) available in preview